# Исчезает Tabs в приложении Android

Tags: tabs, android-viewpager, android, прокрутка, экран

Здравствуйте.

В приложении реализую прокрутку экранов ViewPager с Tabs. При запуске приложения все хорошо, но при переходе между экранами Tabs исчезает, на втором экране появляется стрелка возле названия приложения (только на втором), на которую можно нажать, но ни чего не происходит. А на одном экране (не начальном) присутствует Tabs. На первом экране, тоже исчезает.

Не могу понять, что не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно было использовать метод: ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0)
при перелистывании экранов.